# How to make a MS-DOS system bootable?

Tags: boot

Hey there. I have downloaded a MS-DOS 6.22 OS, added few .exe files, and I'd like to burn them into bootable disk.
All the solutions I found burn the OS to floppy, or uses floppy images on CD's. Problem is that my disk is approx. 4MB which is greater than a floppy image max size. I need to somehow make a CD-R which is bootable.

The OS itself is fully working, however it is NOT bootable when I burn it.
How can I make it bootable? (UltraISO can load "boot file". How can I create such thing?)

Answer (score 4):

One of the solutions that I can think of is make a bootable CD using  bootable DOS floppy image. Configure the bootable dos floppy such that it would load the appropriate drivers for the CD-drive, so that you can access the CD from within your booted DOS environment. A good starting point would be reading through:

- http://www.nu2.nu/bootcd/
- http://nu2.nu/bootdisk/
- http://nu2.nu/bootdisk/cdrom/

I recently created a 32MB bootable USB disk based on the above mentioned instructions.